postgresql (15) Python event_trigger
What's the syntax used to write a Postgresql event trigger in Python? This
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION log_schema_changes()
RETURNS EVENT_TRIGGER
 LANGUAGE plpython3u 
 AS $$ 
import plpy
plyp.warning(TD)
$$; 


CREATE EVENT TRIGGER log_ddl_changes
ON ddl_command_start
WHEN TAG IN ('CREATE TABLE', 'ALTER TABLE', 'DROP TABLE', 'CREATE INDEX', 'ALTER INDEX', 'DROP INDEX')
EXECUTE FUNCTION log_schema_changes();

generates the error message: ERROR:  trigger functions can only be called as triggers
Note: version info psql (15.6 (Ubuntu 15.6-1.pgdg20.04+1), server 15.7 (Ubuntu 15.7-1.pgdg22.04+1))

perhaps your search_path is different from audit? So there is one create function, but in CREATE EVENT TRIGGER you call another function?

Which of the two statements causes the error?

@Melkij yes, that was a typo

@LaurenzAlbe The first part:
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION log_schema_changes() RETURNS EVENT_TRIGGER  LANGUAGE plpython3u   AS $$  import plpy plyp.warning(TD) $$; 

Hm, yes, I can reproduce the error. No idea what causes it; I know little about PL/Python.
